# Flex overlapping 2 child flex layout class set in a row

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have 2 css class leftColumn ad rightColumn arranges in a row layout for a React SPA. The issue is that when the browser is made narrow the rightColumn goes 'under' the leftColumn obscuring the elements therein.

leftColumn overlaying rightColumn

[image: leftColumn overlaying rightColumn]

The code is as follows:

```
            <div className="allWrap">
            <div className="leftColumn" style={{ height: this.height }}>
                <div>
                    <DragLayer snapToGrid={false}/>
                    {/* objects to drag from */}
                    <div className="heading">Drag into the tree below to add item</div>
...etc
            </div>
            <div className="rightColumn">
                <div className="banner" style={{ minWidth: '570px' }}>
                    <img
                        style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
                        src={require('../../Assets/logo_1080x361 copy.svg')}
                        alt={"Logo"}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="view" style={{ padding: '0px', flex: 1, minWidth: '570px' }}>
                    {/* the main view component, we pass clicked element and its content from the state */}
                    <ComponentView/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The css classes look like this:

```
.allWrap {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    min-width: 830px;

    justify-content: space-around;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.leftColumn {
    flex: 1 1 25%;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;

    width: 20%;
    min-width: 270px;
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
}

.rightColumn {
    flex: 3 1 75%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;

    width: 80%;
    min-width: 560px;
    margin-left: 20%;
}
```

Ant ideas how I fix this? I have tried many combinations of flex settings without any influence.

What I need is for the leftColumn and the rightColumn to shrink width wise with the browser window reducing width, each to a minimum size then get each gets horizontal scrollbars

Comment: have you tried flex-wrap: wrap;?

Comment: maybe that's not what you want, there's also flex-shrink and flex-grow that may help

Comment: @Jay as you can clearly see I have full flex directives, which encompass flex-shrink and flex-grow, see the documentation for flex to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I could not get flexbox to lay it out after trying many many combinations. So tried display: grid. Much easier to control if less flexible.

Here are the almost final styles:

```
.allWrap {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: [menu] 270px [inspect] auto;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;

    min-width: 830px;

    overflow: hidden;
}

.leftColumn {
    grid-column-start: menu;
    grid-column-end: inspect;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2; 
    display: grid;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;

    width: 20%;
    min-width: 270px;
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
}

.rightColumn {
    display: grid;
    grid-column-start: inspect;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2; 

    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 560px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

The last thing I need to do is work out how to get rid of the wasted space on the right side of the screen and get the rightColumn to use all width available.

Answer (score 0):

flex-wrap is what you need, try setting it to nowrap.

```
.allWrap {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    min-width: 830px;

    justify-content: space-around;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;

}
```

Comment: Adding flex-wrap: nowrap did not help